# HLComposer Permissions.acl ambiguity regarding logic.js

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

What role am I operating from in the logic.js file composer? If I've defined permissions.acl such that two certain types of participant don't have any access to each other, may I still be able to, in my transaction handler (where both participants are involved by reference in the transaction body) inside logic.js, read/write any party's member variables arbitrarily?

Perhaps in other words, how is the "currentParticipant" determined by a transaction? Say I'm using the following started code for my app https://github.com/IBM/customer-loyalty-program/blob/master/web-app/app.js

The transactions are called by the nodejs runtime and not by a specific participant as far as I understand...

Answer (score 0):

To interact with a hyperledger fabric network you will do as using an identity (certificate + private key). The composer runtime in the chaincode accesses that identity and then looks for the participant that it is mapped to. All identities must be mapped to a participant or you get a message saying the `<common name> with identifier <unique id for the cert> has not been registered`

Commands like composer network start, composer identity issue will bind an identity to a participant for you.

`composer identity bind` takes an existing identity and binds it to an existing participant.